# Padding of span affects iframe height

Tags: html, css

I am working on a piece of code which looks something like this:

```html
<div style="position: relative;">

<span style="display: block;padding-top: 57%;"></span>
<iframe style="    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="https://www.google.com"></iframe>

</div>
```

I do not understand why the padding-top of span gives the iframe height.
Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SolmazK/fnj086nc/)

Answer (score 0):

It's because `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` values expressed in `%` are a percentage of the **width of the containing block**, not of height, if the context width is horizontal.

It's a built in method to provide aspect ratio.

As specified in W3C standards here: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-box-3/#padding-props.

Similarly, in a context with vertical flow direction, all percentage padding properties are expressed as a percentage of the containing block's `height`, including `padding-right` and `padding-left`.